# Font sizes change with amount of page contents in Chrome on Android. What causes this?

Tags: android, html, web

I'm fairly new to mobile website development. While viewing my handiwork in Chrome 40.0.2311.111 on Android 4.1.2 on a Samsung Galaxy S3 mini, I see the font size change depending on the amount of text on the page. Screenshots below show the page with and without content. Note the different font sizes of the header and paragraph text that is being displayed:

[image: Example without content]
[image: Example with content]

The only difference between these two pages is the amount of filler text, everything else is 100% identical. The copyright message (rendered in a smaller font) at the bottom of the page without content is also present on the one with content but is not visible in the screenshot.

The CSS does define font properties:

```
body {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 10pt;
  color: #000033;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 200%;
}
```

Note that I'm relying on inheritance to define the properties of paragraph elements in the body, which should work fine and for me always has. Including a specific definition of font sizes for paragraphs, like so:

```
 p {          /* Include TD as workaround */
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;  /* for Moz inheritance bugs */
  font-size: 10pt;
  color: #000033;
}
```

has no effect.

What causes this behaviour? Am I overlooking something?

Comment: Same problem here, with Samsung Galaxy Note 3 running Android 5.0 and the native Samsung browser (it actually does some worse things)... Hope someone answers this one.